# Command executed from else block in Windows batch script returning wrong errorlevel

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I am new to batch scripting and while fiddling with the simple ones in my Windows 7 pc, I stuck on the following -

```
command1  
echo %errorlevel%  
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 (  
                echo -- Error occured during command1 execution ---           
        goto :eof  
    )   else (   
               echo -- command1 execution was successful ---  
               command2   
               echo %errorlevel%   
               if %errorlevel% neq 0 (              
                   echo -- Error occured during command2 execution ---          
                   goto :eof  
               )    
             )
```

Here, command1 excution is successful(checked separately) and it is returning errorlevel 0(success) while command2 is failing(checked separately) and instead of no zero (failure) it is returning errorlevel as 0. But when I remove else condition, command2 execution is returning 1 (failure). Curious to know the reason.

As suggested, now I am declaring setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the begining and instead of %errorlevel%, using !errorlevel! and it is giving desired errorlevel on success/failure.
But now I am facing another problem. I am calling another command (suppose command3 in place of command2). It inturn calls one of my java class which is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. But in my .bat file it is returning errorlevel as 0, instead of 1 whereas command3 got failed (checked seperately). Below is my latest script -

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
command1  
echo call !errorlevel!
    if !errorlevel! neq 0 (  
                echo -- Error occured during command1 execution ---           
        goto :eof  
    )
               echo -- command1 execution was successful ---  
               REM command3  
               java MyclassName > logfilename.log 2>&1                   
               echo call !errorlevel!   
               if !errorlevel! neq 0 (              
                   echo -- Error occured during command3 execution ---          
                   goto :eof  
               )                      
echo --- command3 Executoin was successful---
```

How to force !errorlevel! to return correct value when it is failed with some exception. Please help.

Comment: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is the key here. where is the rest of the script?

Comment: Thanks @GerhardBarnard. What does setlocal enabledelayedexpansion do and how can I use it in my script. My script is only missing '@echo off' at first line and 'echo --- execution was successful ---' at last line.

Comment: By " when I remove else condition, command2 execution is returning 1 " - I meant to say - executing statements inside else block by removing the else condition only i.e removing only else( ). Please let me know if you still have any more doubt.

Comment: Hi @GerhardBarnard your answer was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Now I am declaring setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the begining and instead of %errorlevel%, using !errorlevel! and it is giving desired errorlevel on success/failure. But now I am facing another problem. I am calling another command (suppose command3 in place of command2). It inturn calls one of my java class which is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. But in my .bat file it is returning errorlevel as 0, instead of 1 whereas command3 got failed. How can I make errorlevel to return currect vaue. Please help

Comment: Please edit your question and show all the new code.

Comment: `call echo !errorlevel!`: `call` was successful, so  the new errorlevel will be zero. Use just `echo !errorlevel!` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

With your current code, if you want to *display* the actual error returned by `command2` use

```
           CALL echo %%errorlevel%%
```

and if you want to execute an `if` on the *run-time* value of `errorlevel`, then use

```
           if errorlevel 1 (
```

`IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0.

Comment: Hi @Magoo, your answer is useful, thanks. Now I am declaring setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the begining and instead of %errorlevel%, using !errorlevel! and it is giving desired errorlevel on success/failure. But now I am facing another problem. I am calling another command (suppose command3 in place of command2). It inturn calls one of my java class which is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. But in my .bat file it is returning errorlevel as 0, instead of 1 whereas command3 got failed. How can I make errorlevel to return currect vaue. Please help.

Comment: @DebaprasadJana Please post your amended script into an edit in your question so we can see what is wrong now.

Comment: As suggested, reposted my question. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @GerhardBarnard, any suggestion to resolve this issue??

Comment: @DebaprasadJana but you run `call` which is successful, so it will be 0, also first loop says goto eof? just do `echo !errorlevel!` and not `call echo !errorlevel!`

Comment: @DebaprasadJana see my answer below with amended code

Answer (score 1):

Try this amended version of the code, let's actually use the `if` and `else`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
command1 2>&1
echo !errorlevel!
if !errorlevel! neq 0 (  
         echo -- Error occured during command1 execution ---        
     ) else (
          echo -- command1 execution was successful ---
          command3 2>&1
          echo !errorlevel!
              if !errorlevel! neq 0 (              
                   echo -- Error occured during command3 execution ---          
               ) else (                     
                   echo --- command3 Execution was successful---
           )
      )
```

Comment: Hi @GerhardBarnard, the purpose of goto :eof is to force the script not to execute any further commands if it meets an error. Anyways, your above solution is also not working as command3 is still echoing 0 instead of 1 (as it throwing exception) and hence it is not coming inside the subsequent if block.

Comment: @DebaprasadJana ok, now we goto the next question, what is this `command3` you are using? Please also copy your output to your question so I can see.

Comment: @DebaprasadJana See the edit again, I implemented else as it should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your trials, but its not working. command3 is still returning errorlevel 0 hence its not coming inside the subsequent if block. So, it is printing - command3 Execution was successful.

Comment: @DebaprasadJana again, please tell me what this command is you are using. You are probably doing something you think will work differently than it is.

Comment: Hi @Gerhard Barnard, I am using-  java MyclassName > logfilename.log 2>&1  in place of command3. I have update this in my question also. Problem is, though MyclassName is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (checked in the log file), the errorlevel, it is returning in the script is 0.

Comment: cmd is getting errorlevel 0 because java exececuted as expected, yet java itself caused exceptions. Java exceptions will not create batch file errorlevels, so you would perhaps rather need to run a `for loop` to launch java and then catch the exceptions and create errorlevel based on that.

Comment: Ok, will look into that. Thanks @Gerhard Barnard.